# How to make my server trust with a certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, certificate, trust

On my java application, that runs on Tomcat in a RedHat linux machine, I need to send a request to an API that uses ssl trust certificate. Our partners have already sent us two files that should be used to trust them: `wse-tst_partner_com.crt` and `DigiCertCA.crt`.

Our partners have sent these instructions: https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/apache-openssl.htm#ssl_certificate_install

However, I'm stuck on step 2, since I didn't find an `httpd.conf` file, neither `apache2.conf` file. I wonder if these are not applicable to Tomcat (they didn't actually know what we have before creating the API and their security stuff).

I've also tried to look for installing trust certificates for Tomcat, but the instructions I've found were only to create a new certificate with `keytool` - I don't want to create a new certificate, I need to "trust" the ones our partners already created.

I've also found [this question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/200789/how-do-you-configure-apache-tomcat-to-trust-internal-certificate-authorities-for). However, I don't have any `.pem` files, and I don't want to create new files - I just want to use the ones I mentioned on the beginning of this post.

I'm a noob in this subject - I don't think this should be a complicated task... Should I add something to my `server.xml` file? Or, maybe I'm looking for the `conf` files in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`httpd.conf` and `apache2.conf`  are apache files not tomcat.
They assumed you were using apache instead of tomcat.

Either put an apache in front of tomcat and use that guide or create a keystore with keytool (A keystore is "like a box" containing the certificates) and add the certificates you were provided inside, you will need to add the intermediate and the root as well. And then configure tomcat (listeners, connectors) to use that keystore.

Follow the steps from this guide instead https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/tomcat-keytool.htm but ignore the creation of certificate as the certificates are already provided. Make sure you have the key as well, otherwise you'll have to create the CSR in the server and provide that to whoever signs the certificates (your partner I guess) and they will get back to you with new certificates. Incorporate the certs to the keystore as suggested.